# How can I update the icon of a given JLabel during runtime?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

SOLVED: The set setRoomImage method was never called on the RoomTile Object. Thanks to @sorifiend for noticing this!

I currently place JLabels using this method:

```
public void spawnItem(Entity e, int x, int y, int i, int j) {
    bgLabel[i][j] = new JLabel();
    bgLabel[i][j].setBounds(x,y,e.width,e.height);
    bgLabel[i][j].setIcon(e.sprite);
    layeredPane.add(bgLabel[i][j], e.layer);
}
```

Where bgLabel[][] is an array of JLabels and e.sprite is an imageIcon as shown in the Entity Class below. As well, e.layer is the appropriate Integer (i.e. 0, 100, 200).
The Entity Class looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Entity {
    public int width, height;
    ImageIcon sprite;
    Integer layer;
}
```

And I extend the entity class like this:

```
import java.net.URL;

public class RoomTile extends Entity{
    boolean light;

    public RoomTile(boolean isLight) {
        height = 52;
        width = 52;
        layer = 0;
        light = isLight;
    }

    public void setRoomImage(String s) {
        URL url;
        if (light) {
            url = getClass().getResource("Assets/" + s + ".png");
        } else {
            url = getClass().getResource("Assets/Dark" + s + ".png");
        }
        sprite = new ImageIcon(url);
    }
}
```

All JLabels are placed by nested for loop iterating over a 2d array, the object is then added to the layered pane using the spawnItem method. This all works properly and a grid of objects, such as rooms, are placed and visible. However, when attempting to change the icon of these JLabels, they simply disappear.
I am using the method setLight to receive the label that is desired to be changed:

```
public void setLight(int i, int j) {
    RoomTile lightRoom = new RoomTile(true);
    bgLabel[i][j].setIcon(lightRoom.sprite);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

The setLight method is within a class which extends JFrame.
When setLight is called, the JLabel at the grid position provided, simply disappears, rather than its icon changing. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `setLight` method you never call `lightRoom.setRoomImage(...);` so the sprite in null. therefore when you use `bgLabel[i][j].setIcon(lightRoom.sprite);` the icon is removed completly. To fix this you need to call `lightRoom.setRoomImage(...);` before `bgLabel[i][j].setIcon(lightRoom.sprite);` Note: That when you call `revalidate()` will cause the layout manager to recalculate the layout and resize the JLabels to suit (what happens when they no longer have an icon and no border? poof), which you don't need to do if you are simply swapping the JLabel image/icon to one of the same size.

Comment: @sorifiend You're so right, omg. A fresh pair of eyes was really all I needed. Tkank you for taking the time to read through my incoherent rambling.